# Suprisingly big array for Test/Training Set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a predictive model using linear regression with a dataset that has 157673 entries.

The data (in a csv file) is in such format:

```
Timestamp,Signal_1,Signal_2,Signal_3,Signal_4,Signal_5
2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
```

My current code:

```
filename = 'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename , parse_dates=['Timestamp'], header=0)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']))
u, v, w, x, y, z = df.values.T

X = np.asarray([v, w, x, y, z])
Y = np.asarray([u, u, u, u, u])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)

lineReg = LinearRegression()
lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score: ', lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
print('Weights: ', lineReg.coef_)
```

When printing out the shape of both X and Y it is `(5, 157673)`

However now I am running into the error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 185. GiB for an array with shape (157673, 157673) and data type float64`.

Why is that? There must be a mistake somewhere and if not, why is it suddenly in the shape of `(157673, 157673)` instead of `(6, 157673)` ?

Comment: The data should have shape `(157673, 5)`; observations go into rows. When `LinearRegression` tries to compute the covariance matrix it tries to produce a 157673x157673 matrix instead of a 5x5 matrix, which blows your memory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the dimensions of your data must be (157673, 5) instead of (5, 157673). Therefore, the covariance matrix will be a 5x5 matrix.

Usually, in machine learning, observations go into rows.